# @*android in android style XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-styles

In an android project, while writing XML resources, I have often seen people referring to android's system resources as:

```
@android:attribute type/ attribute name
```

and

```
@*android:attribute type/ attribute name
```

Could anyone elaborate on what the `*` sign does?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but often the asterix defines a wildcard. On the Android site the following page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html says the asterix:

- 'android:pathPattern' - Denotes a wildcard
- 'android:mimeTypeIndicate'- any subtypes can be used.

While on the W3Schools site about XPath it states
@*  Matches any attribute node
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp